# Preposition followed by participial phrase

Tags: prepositions, gerund-phrases, participial-phrases

For example,

> **After** brushing my teeth, I go to bed

Is this a participial phrase, or a prepositional phrase, or both?

> Brushing my teeth...

Is participial, but the **after** is making me think that the former is not a participial phrase. 
What is this called?

Comment: If the verb of the verb phrase is a participle, then it's a participial phrase. That's usually just a participial clause that's missing its subject (the subject is _my_ when the predicate is _brushing my teeth_, and it's not present in the clause, but it's understood, like _you_ in imperatives). When it comes after a preposition like _after_, it's still just a clause or phrase, but it's introduced by the preposition. You can consider it a prepositional phrase with a clause or phrase as its object, or as a subordinate clause or phrase introduced by a subordinator. It makes no difference.

Comment: @JohnLawler I thought of something else. Brushing my teeth is a gerund phrase isn't it?

Comment: It can be considered a gerund, if the clause is used as a noun phrase. That's one of the interpretations I mentioned above: prepositions take noun phrases as objects, so if you think of _after brushing my teeth_ as a prepositional phrase, then _brushing my teeth_ can be considered a gerund.

Answer (score 1):

According to CGEL (p. 641), *after brushing my teeth* is a preposition phrase. Its head is the preposition *after*, while the gerund-participial clause *brushing my teeth* is its complement.

Other types of clauses can also be complements of prepositions. Here is the relevant section of CGEL; the relevant example is [19vii]:

> **5 The structure and functions of PPs**
>
> **5.1 Complementation**
>
> **(e) Complements with the form of clauses**
>
> [19]   i  *This happened [after **Stacy left**].*                                       [non-expandable declarative]
>            ii  *I'll do it [provided **that you help me**].*                                     [expandable declarative]
>           iii  *[Although (**we were**) nearly exhausted,] we pressed on.*             [reducible declarative]
>           iv  *Let me repeat [lest **there be any doubt about the terms**].*                     [subjunctive]
>            v  *They ignored the question [of **whether it was ethical**].*                           [interrogative]
>           vi  *We can't agree [ on **how much to charge**].*                             [infinitival interrogative]
>          vii  *They're talking [about **moving to New York**].*                                [gerund-participial]
>         viii  *He's not as enthusiastic [as **he used to be**].*                                                 [comparative]
>
> Non-interrogative infinitivals are found with the expressions *in order* and *so as*: *He only mentioned it [in order **to embarrass his wife**]* or *We left at dawn [so as **to miss the rush-hour traffic**].* Constructions with clausal complements are dealt with in the context of our discussion of subordinate clauses in Chs. 11,13, and 14. Note that in *They kept blaming him [for **what he had done**]* the underlined constituent is not a clause but an NP (a fused relative), and hence does not belong under the present heading.

Comment: Okay, so the gerund-participial phrase is not a participle to 'I go to bed'

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, no. But now consider this sentence: *I go to bed brushing my teeth.* Now the gerund-participal clause *brushing my teeth* functions as a [catenative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb) complement to the verb *go*.